# C# SQLCe Inserting new rows with DataSet without loading the whole table?

Tags: c#, insert, datatable, dataset, sql-server-ce

I've a SQLCe database with a table. In the application there is a method which should **only** inserting new rows to this table.

I'm wondering what is the best practise for doing so. When working with a DataSet one has to load the **whole** table into it.

To me this seems like a big overkill, since I only want to insert new rows and therefore there is no need to fill the DataSet with the entire table.

On the other hand it also seems very ineffective to manually insert every single row with an explicit INSERT statement.

So in order to do a "batch"-INSERT one would go with a DataSet. Is there a possibility to work with a DataSet without filling the entire table, e.g. get only the schema of the table and then insert the rows to the DataSet?

Many thanks,

Juergen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with DataSet against a SQL Server Compact database is vey inefficient . you should use SqlCeResultSet or my wrapper lbrar, that allows you to do batch INSERTs very fast, based on a DataTable, a DataReader or even a List of objects. http://sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com

Comment: thx for the link. The SqlCeBulkCopy is what I was looking for.